# Writing Emails to CSV Resulting in Only One Column

Tags: python, csv

I have this script I'm using that I got online and modified a bit. Basically what I want is to scrape all the emails in my inbox and save them to a CSV with **Email, First Name, Last Name** format. So far it is saving all that info into one column of CSV instead of three..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Very basic example of using Python 3 and IMAP to iterate over emails in a
# gmail folder/label.  This code is released into the public domain.
#
# This script is example code from this blog post:
# http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/07/25/gmail-email-with-python-via-imap/
#
# This is an updated version of the original -- modified to work with Python 3.4.
#
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import email.header
import datetime
import csv


EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "test@email.com"

# Use 'INBOX' to read inbox.  Note that whatever folder is specified, 
# after successfully running this script all emails in that folder 
# will be marked as read.
EMAIL_FOLDER = "INBOX"


def process_mailbox(M):
    """
    Do something with emails messages in the folder.  
    For the sake of this example, print some headers.
    """

    rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print("No messages found!")
        return

    emailList = []
    out = open('email_list.csv', 'w')
    for num in data[0].split():
        rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print("ERROR getting message", num)
            return

        msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1]) # Contains all the message info including header and content
        hdr = email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(msg['From']))
        sender = str(hdr)
        emailList.append(sender)
        #out.write(sender)
        #out.write('\n')

    for c in emailList:
        print (c.split(" "))
        out.write(c)
        out.write('\n')

    out.close()


##        print('Raw Date:', msg['Date'])
##        # Now convert to local date-time
##        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
##        if date_tuple:
##            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
##                email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
##            print ("Local Date:", \
##                local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))


M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

try:
    rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, 'password')
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print ("LOGIN FAILED!!! ")
    sys.exit(1)

print(rv, data)

rv, mailboxes = M.list()
if rv == 'OK':
    print("Mailboxes:")
    print(mailboxes)

rv, data = M.select(EMAIL_FOLDER)
if rv == 'OK':
    print("Processing mailbox...\n")
    process_mailbox(M)
    M.close()
else:
    print("ERROR: Unable to open mailbox ", rv)

M.logout()
```

Which prints out in such format:

```
['John', 'Doe', '<mail-noreply@google.com>']
['Joe', 'Doe', '<mail-noreply@google.com>']
['Jacob', 'Doe', '<mail-noreply@google.com>']
['Homer', 'Simpson-Doh!', '<mail-noreply@google.com>']
```

But in CSV it prints all that info into one column like this:

```
      Column 1
Row 1 John Doe <mail-noreply@google.com>
Row 2 Joe Doe <mail-noreply@google.com>
Row 3 Jacob Doe <mail-noreply@google.com>
```

But I need 3 columns instead..tried doing out.write(c.split(" ")) but that results in an error.

Comment: You don't actually have one column, I when you read the file with the csv module you will have three columns

Comment: Really? I opened it with notepad too and its all one column for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is `join` what you're looking for?

```
>>> foo = ['John', 'Doe', '<mail-noreply@google.com>']
>>> print(",".join(foo))
John,Doe,<mail-noreply@google.com>
```

Although taking a look at [the CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) might be fun for you.

Comment: This isn't working for me - seems to do the same thing.